# Collapse/Expand buttons for the Search Bar Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I modify the code from this Codepen to have 'expand all' and 'collapse all' buttons?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZgebe

Included JS:

```
(function(){
 var searchTerm, panelContainerId;
 // Create a new contains that is case insensitive
 $.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function (n, i, m) {
   return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
 };

 $('#accordion_search_bar').on('change keyup paste click', function () {
   searchTerm = $(this).val();
   $('#accordion > .panel').each(function () {
    panelContainerId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
   $(panelContainerId + ':not(:containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + 
'))').hide();
  $(panelContainerId + ':containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + 
')').show();
  });
  });
}());
```

Also, if I ultimately have sub-accordions inside these accordions - what do i need to do for those to be included in this 'collapse/expand' feature or should they work out of hand?

Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Check demo **[here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/VxzNEL?editors=0010)**

JS

```
  $(".btn-expand-all").on("click", function() {
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("show");
  });
  $(".btn-collapse-all").on("click", function() {
    $(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, Jyoti!  That worked perfectly.  I inserted that JS into index.js and added the buttons to the HTML.  Excellent!  

Not sure if i need to open another question for this, but:  Is there an easy way to block certain accordions from reacting to these buttons?

Comment: @BlueDaNoob yes you can block certain block from reacting to these buttons. since every panel has `panel-collpase` in common. You can add your custom class to `panel-collapse` and pass that class to panel show-hide method. Therefore only those panel will be collapse and expand which contains your `custom class` on click of button.